# Should Meta Classes in Models Inherit From Object

Tags: python, django

It seems pretty conventional to write models something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ("name")
```

Is there any reason `class Meta:` is used, and not `class Meta(object):`? Is there any reason not to explicitly inherit from `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as Stephen's answer, note that from version 2.0, Django only supports Python 3; in that version of Python there is no need to inherit from object, all classes are automatically "new-style".

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from `object` should make no difference.  The pattern:

```
class Foo():
    class Meta:
       attribute = 'This is Interesting'
```

Is primarily to make is easy to later code something like:

```
if Foo.Meta.attribute == 'How Boring':
    ....
```

In this pattern the only functionality is accessing the class attributes of `Meta` so any other functionality of `Meta` probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually, while your point is valid, this example is not so well chosen because django will do some voodoo with the attributes of the `Meta` class of `Model` subclass, so that there is no guarantee that your snippet will work.